# Add page number to Title and meta desc

Tags: pagination, meta

Want to add page number to title and meta description because I have a lot of duplicates. Could you tell me how I can do it?

Comment: What's a "page number" (the entry ID?) and where do you want to add this? To the entries' titles when they are saved, or in a template when the entries are rendered?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add more details about your current setup for a more specific answer.

In general, adding a number to the Meta Title and Meta Description is probably not a good approach to solve your problem of duplicates. Search engines score your page based on how relevant your content is. Adding a number, unless it has some meaning (perhaps a date for an event, tax form number, or [241543903](https://www.google.com/search?q=241543903&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS754US754&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwif2q2srWAhXB4iYKHTZeDvkQ_AUICigB&biw=1547&bih=905)), is just going to be noise and not help your page rank in any meaningful way.

Consider what other data you have in your posts. Can you add the name of a category some items are in? Can you add the name of a User that posted the content? Often there is a way to take a generic page and add a second dimension of data to make it more meaningful.

```
Generic Name - Category 1 - Site Name
Generic Name - Category 2 - Site Name
```

Alternatively, if the pages really are not meaningful, consider pointing search engines to [a more meaningful canonical URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en). For example, if you have a paginated index page, sometimes all the secondary pages will appear to have the same metadata.

In these cases you can add the `canonical` meta tag to point back to the primary page as the one that should be recognized by search engines.

```
https://website.com/section (points to self with metadata)

https://website.com/section/2 (points to main section page with metadata)
<link rel="canonical" href="https://website.com/section" />
```